# Why does the official CLI app generate a new address when asked to check balances?

Tags: iota-cli

The official iota-cli app on the IOTA repo has a `balance` command which is supposed to calculate the balance for the logged in seed.

Sometimes, the command takes ages. I wondered and looked into the code. It seems, as if the balances command first calls `getNewAddress`. Why is that?

Here is the code: https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app/blob/9266d7af4de57be0f70ce5b8778981301d5c0657/lib/commands/balance.js#L26

Answer (score 2):

When you call `getNewAddress` with `returnAll: true`, it will not only return the new address but all other addresses before that one too. And you have to know all addresses to be able to ask for their balances.

`getNewAddress` will not attach the new address or anything, just compute addresses until it finds one that has never been used before i.e. [`findTransactions`](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/reference#findtransactions)  doesn't return any transactions.